# Reusing computed values within the same SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Background

I'm maintaining a complex stored procedure for, essentially, committing staged changes to a final inventory. There are a couple of linked fields in what it does, as:

```
INSERT INTO (itemNumber, itemCode) ' and a lot more columns
SELECT stageNumber, Inventory.ConstructItemCode(stageNumber) ' and a lot more columns
FROM Inventory.Staging WHERE state = @final
```

### Problem

Our process for determining the final item number is going to get a lot more complex. I don't want to do:

```
INSERT INTO (itemNumber, itemCode)
SELECT *a complicated case statement*, Inventory.ConstructItemCode(*the same complicated case statement*)
FROM Inventory.Staging WHERE state = @final
```

because of duplication concerns, and while it's possible to do this:

```
INSERT INTO (itemNumber, itemCode)
SELECT i.caseNumber, Inventory.ConstructItemCode(i.caseNumber)
FROM (SELECT *a complicated case statement* as caseNumber 
      FROM Inventory.Staging WHERE state = @final) i
```

I'd also have to stick all the other columns I needed into the intermediate select, and properly qualify them on the way out, right? Is there a way to remember the result of the case statement and use it again within the same select, or am I stuck bubbling everything through that intermediate select statement?

Comment: Have you investigated using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to compute the complicated CASE statement exactly once, and then select from the CTE to do everything you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

### In this case, a CTE

The staging table does have a key field, we just haven't needed it to do the move before. So I wound up doing this:

```
WITH case_cte (stageKey, caseNumber) 
  AS (SELECT stageKey, *a complicated case statement* 
      FROM Inventory.Staging WHERE state = @final)
INSERT INTO (itemNumber, itemCode) ' and a lot more columns
SELECT c.CaseNumber, Inventory.ConstructItemCode(c.CaseNumber) ' and a lot more columns
FROM Inventory.Staging a INNER JOIN case_cte c ON a.stageKey = c.stageKey
```

moving the where clause up into the CTE to restrict that selection.